# How to add emoji to lokalise strings that will be used by Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, lokalise

Not sure how to put an emoji into a string into Lokalise so that both mobile platforms can use it natively

Answer (score 0):

it might take you some time to find this info, but it seems to me that Lokalise at this moment is using utf-16 encodings.

So to put an emoji into string use this notation:

"[/uD83D/uDE01](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1F601)"

You are welcome to suggest some best practices and correct me